# how to differentiate between different inputs in the same html form using php

Tags: php, html

I'm building a chatbot in php I want the functionality of that chatbot to be that it is used for resetting the password, so it asks for employee's `PIS_CODE` which it uses as a primary key to change the password in the password column, you can see my database table.

[image]

see it has columns `PIS_CODE` and password, so I ask the user for `PIS_CODE` and then it asks the user for the new password and then it changes the password in the corresponding column

so I've been able to take the `PIS_CODE` and use it as a primary key to reset the password but the password which is reset is the `PIS_CODE` itself

[image]

see here I wanted to reset the password for 41000000 `PIS_CODE` but it reset the password to 41000000 itself. So it seems like my chatbot assumes the input value to be the pis code and it updates the password column with that value only, so my chatbot is not able to differentiate between different inputs. Plus I want to use only a single form and a single input field.
you can see my chatbot here.

[image]

**HTML Code :**

```
<div class="form-group">
  <form action="process.php" id="form" name="f2" method="POST" >
    <input type="textarea" id="tt" name="input" placeholder="Type Your Message" style="position:absolute; bottom:0; height:30px; width:100%; height:50px;" required />

</div>

// this is the code which takes the input for the PIS_CODE
$msgg=$_POST['input'];

// this is the code which takes the input for the password
$pass=$_POST['input'];

// the problem is it saves the same input(that is PIS_CODE) in both the variables($msgg and $pass)
```

**FULL Code:**

```
<?php
require_once("config.php");
$msgg=$_POST['input'];
$msg=strtolower($msgg);
$ID = $msg;
$length=strlen($msg);
$flag=0;

$pass=$_POST['input'];
$update = "UPDATE lala SET password='$pass' WHERE PIS_CODE=".$msg;
$res_4=mysqli_query($con,$update);

$sql1 = "SELECT * FROM lala WHERE PIS_CODE='$msg'";
$res_u = mysqli_query($con, $sql1);

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
</head>
<style>
.in
{
   background-color:rgb(64,128,255);
   color:white;
   padding:10px; 
   right:0;
   width:130px;
   text-align: center;
   height:auto;
   border-radius: 5px;
   margin-left: 120px;
   margin-bottom: 5px; 
}
.out
{
    background-color:rgb(241,240,240);
    color:black;
    padding:10px; 
    left:5; 
    width:130px;
    text-align: center;
    height:auto;
    border-radius: 15px;
}
</style>
<body>
<div class="in">
<?php echo "$msgg"; ?>
</div><br>
<div class="out">
<?php

if (($_POST['input']) =='password reset') 
{
echo "Do you want to reset your password? "; 
}
else if (($_POST['input']) =='yes') 
{
echo "Sure, Please provide PIS code ";   
}
if (mysqli_num_rows($res_u) == 1) 
{
echo 'Pis verified';
echo "Enter new password";
}

if($update){//if the update worked

      echo "Update successful!";



    } 
 ?>
</div><br>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: but if i add another input field it dosen't work

Comment: _**Never ever** ever never_ store passwords in plain text! You should _always_ hash the passwords using [password_hash()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and only store the hashes. Then you can use [password_verify()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) to verify a password against a hash.

Comment: **Warning!** You are _wide open_ for SQL injection attacks! You should use parameterized [prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of using completely unescaped user data directly in your queries like that.

Comment: this is a code in progress after I am able to solve this problem, of-course i'm going to encrypt it

Comment: Encrypt it all you want, it will still be vulnerable to SQL injection.  Take Magnus's warning seriously or someone will be able to easily destroy your database.

Comment: Seems this is flawed, if this worked I could provide anyone else's identifier and change their password.  Assuming your chat client has an ID associated with their session, could you not look up via that, and instead of splitting commands over a series of questions, how about a syntax like 'SET PASSWORD=blah'?

Comment: this is a private server not a public one,  only a certain number of people could access it from the data center where the PC's are behind locked glass doors which could only be accessed by biometric verification, so I don't think such drastic methods are necessary for such a case, simple encryption should be sufficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `PHP` session. This would do what you want:

```
require_once("config.php");
$msgg=$_POST['input'];
$msg=strtolower($msgg);
$ID = $msg;
$length=strlen($msg);
$flag=0;

session_start(); 

if(isset($_SESSION['PIS_CODE'])){
    $pass=$_POST['input'];
    $update = "UPDATE lala SET password='$pass' WHERE PIS_CODE=".$_SESSION['PIS_CODE'];
    $res_4=mysqli_query($con,$update);
    unset($_SESSION['PIS_CODE']);
}
else{
    $sql1 = "SELECT * FROM lala WHERE PIS_CODE='$msg'";
    $res_u = mysqli_query($con, $sql1);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($res_u) == 1) {
        $_SESSION['PIS_CODE'] = $msg;
    }
}
```

If i were you (i.e. working on a chatbot), i'd use the `$_SESSION` object for more than that. You could keep your simple 1 input form, and use `PHP` session to keep information about the next expected answer, or for a serie of questions like in your example, to know what is  the current question, an many other possible usage.

Comment: i am new to this so you're saying that i can use session to  keep information about the next expected answer, how can I achieve that?